# The attribute update is not defined in the component commandButton

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have this JSF commandButton which I use to delete rows from table:

```
<h:commandButton id="deleterow" value="HiddenDelete"  action="#{BatteryProfileTabGeneralController.saveData}" style="display:none" update="growl">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

In Netbeans 7.3 I get this error:

```
The attribute update is not defined in the component commandButton
```

I use `update` attribute to display message when I successfully delete row. Can I replace this attribute with similar attribute?

Comment: `update` is a primefaces only attribute, which can't be used on stock JSF components (like the `<h:commandButton/>` you have there). The `render` attribute on the `<f:ajax/>` should be sufficient to achieve the desired effect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `update` attribute is specific to PrimeFaces [`<p:commandButton>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/commandButton.html). It's a convenience replacement of the  standard JSF equivalent [`<f:ajax render>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html).

So, basically, the `<p:commandButton ... update="growl" />` does essentially the same as:

```
<h:commandButton ...>
    <f:ajax render="growl" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Note that when the `<p:growl id="growl">` is not inside the same form, then you should refer it using an absolute client ID instead, perhaps `<f:ajax render=":growl">`. If you would like to update the current form as well, then use `<f:ajax render="@form :growl">`. This is perhaps your case as you've currently already a `render="@form"` but still keeps asking about explicitly updating the growl, which suggests that it is *actually* not enclosed in the form at all.